# Keyboard not shown on inflated editText even after clicking on it

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

### Background

I have a form-like activity, which has some views that can be created dynamically upon pressing.

I'm using an xml for each field that is inflated upon clicking on a button.

What I need is that upon choosing to add a new item, it will get focus, scroll if needed, and show the keyboard so that the user can type things into it. The keyboard may be shown upon adding the field or when clicking on the EditText.

### The problem

For some reason, on some devices (and I don't think it's even an android version issue) when inflating the new view, the editText within it can get focus but it doesn't show the keyboard, even if it has focus and the user clicks on it.

In such a case, the only way to show the keyboard is to click on another EditText.

I've tested it, and noticed that it doesn't occur when I don't use xml at all, meaning when i create the views only in code.

### The question

Why does it occur? What can I do in order to fix it?

I've already tried so many possible solutions, but none work on all devices.

### Sample Code

the next code has the described issue on xperia j (android 4.0.4) an galaxy mini (android 2.3.6) .

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
            // using the next code works when using it instead of inflating a layout:
            // final EditText editText = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            // editText.setText("item " + container.getChildCount());
            container.addView(view);
        }
    });
}
```

the field layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFffffff"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/typeSpinner"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@null"
        android:padding="5dp" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/removeItemView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        layout="@layout/remove_item_view" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/fieldEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/removeItemView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/typeSpinner"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:hint="field"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:minWidth="200dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" >
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

the main layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="click"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

---

EDIT: found a partial solution which won't show the keyboard right away, but at least it will be shown when pressing the editText:

```
public static void forceFocusOnView(final View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return;
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.clearFocus();
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in a reason of that problem. Could be some missmatches when Android sdk were rewritten in order to match some devices.
So I think that the best solution to you is to show your keyboard manually and do not try to move a train, just take the path of the least resistance:

```
EditText et=(EditText)this.findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                 imm.showSoftInput(et, 0);<----------------

        }
    });
```

Here you go , man. Wish you luck.

Oh i see...

```
private EditText et;
private Runnable setFocus;
......
protected void onCreate(...){
.
.
.
 setFocus=new Runnable(){

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    et.requestFocus();

                }
            };
}
....
 findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
      //try this:
        et=(EditText)view.findViewById(r.id.fieldEditText);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.showSoftInput(et, 0);<----------------

    }
});
        container.addView(view);
        container.requestLayout();<--------------
        et.postDelayed(setFocus,300);
    }
});
```

Comment: sadly this is one of the things i've already tested. it didn't work on those devices. i've also tried to play with the focus requests, but even if i succeed, it might not work well on other devices as it might hide & show the keyboard, providing a weird user experience. another thing i've tried is to do the same operation for onTouchListener, upon the UP touch action... i will try what you've written again, as i might be wrong with how i've written it.

Comment: ok, i've tested it, and if i choose to set the focus on the new editText in the inflated layout (which is important so that it will scroll to the new item and show the user that the item was created) , the keyboard won't show.

Comment: is using a delayed message a wise thing to use? i mean, some devices might need more, and some devices might need less time...

Comment: it didn't work on galaxy mini. it didn't show the keyboard, even after clicking the edittext again.

Comment: try to add  container.requestView() after addView();

Comment: can you please edit your answer? i'm not sure which parts i should put and which i shouldn't.

Comment: should i have the part of the setOnFocusChangeListener ?

Comment: it almost worked. when there are many items for example that fill the screen, and i choose to add a new item, it scrolls to it but it doesn't show the whole EditText, only half of it.

Comment: try to add an xml attribute android:animateLayoutChanges="true" or something like that to your container LinearLayout. And I think this is another question))))...

Comment: it didn't help. however, i've found an alternative, which doesn't show the keyboard right away, but after clicking the edittext, it will be shown. soon i'll update my question.