# Keyboard is not shown for Edit Text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity which has a layout containing two linear layouts.

1. First linear layout changes on click events performed by user
2. Second linear layout is constant throughout the application

When user performs some click actions, I am adding the fragment to the first layout as

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.llFragmentContainer, FragmentClassObject, "fragment_detail");
```

Then within the fragment's `onCreateView` method. I am inflating the view I want to show to the user.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.personal_stuff, container,
                false);
```

Now personal_stuff layout has some edit text fields.

Problem :

After the first linear layout is inflated with a fragment. keyboard is not shown to the user when EditText in personal_stuff layout is focused/Clicked.

What could be the problem ?? Any suggestions ??

Comment: even on taping Edittext widget its not bringing Keyboard ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149800/keyboard-not-shown-on-inflated-edittext-even-after-clicking-on-it

Comment: @Techfist nope. I tried tapping on edit text, but keyboard is not shown :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void forceFocusOnView(final View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return;
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.clearFocus();
            view.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    view.requestFocus();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

with

```
forceFocusOnView(myView);
```

EDIT : public spelling was incorrect so corrected that